# How to append specific data on table using jquery

Tags: jquery

At first `AJAX` call it should be getting: Preliminaries, Professional Services

At second `AJAX` call it should be getting:  "Building Requirements", "Permits, Bonds & Insurances, Etc." (it suppose it be append on under the preliminaries)," As Built Fee"(this suppose to be append under the Professional Service)

But what happens, is all of the data for second `AJAX` call append on the Professional Services

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Pmms/GetPhases',
  data: {
    projectId: '@Model.Data.Id'
  },
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function(index, value) {
      console.log(value);
      var toAppend = `<tbody>
                              <tr class="phase bg-secondary" data-id="${value.projectTaskId}">
                                  <td colspan="7">
                                      ${value.tasks}
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                      </tbody>`;
      $('#tableForContent').append(toAppend);
      $.each((value.projectSubTaskCollection).split(','), function(index, val) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/Pmms/GetActivityName',
          data: {
            actId: val
          },
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(datas) {
            var workItem = `<tr class="activity bg-danger" data-id="${datas.list.dataKey}">
                                <td colspan="6" class="pl-3">
                                    &nbsp;${datas.list.dataValue}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btnToAdd">
                                        add
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`;
            $('#tableForContent tbody').last().append(workItem);
          },
          error: function(error) {

          }
        });
      });
    });
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.error('Error fetching JSON data:', error);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Your ajax call results are not sequential.  They can come back in any order depending on how long they take to run.  So your `tr` calls may take longer than the `tbody` calls - and your `tr` calls all add to the `.last()` tbody.   Options: 1) implement an ajax queue (so you don't DDoS your own server) 2) load more data at once instead of multiple ajax calls 3) link the tbody and the tr results together somehow (eg `let thisTbody = $(toAppend).appendTo('#tableForContent')` then use `thisTbody` instead of tbody.last()

Comment: add some `console.log` debugging into each `success:` so you can see what order it's coming back in.